# Cannot edit sendmail configuration on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5.3

Tags: linux, sendmail, redhat, rpm, rhel

Have been through 10 or so Red Hat Enterprise Linux servers to update some `sendmail` configuration options and finally got to a 5.3 release server that is missing the `sendmail-cf` package and the server has no RHN access etc.

Tried searching online for a suitable RPM to manually install but can't seem to locate one?

```
[root@ ~]# make -C /etc/mail                                             make: Entering directory `/etc/mail'
WARNING: 'sendmail.mc' is modified. Please install package sendmail-cf to update your configuration.
make: Leaving directory `/etc/mail'
```

Help please?

Answer (score 0):

The server does not need to have direct access to RHN. If you have '10 or so Red Hat Enterprise Linux servers', then I assume you also have a the subscriptions for them. You can login to your RHN account, download the sendmail-cf RPM for RHEL 5.3, copy it to the server and install it from there with yum.